# function createOrders() logic in OverviewPost.php in module-multishipping

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, orders, multishipping

I got function `createOrders()` in file `OverviewPost.php` locate in `module-multishipping` like below.

```
$this->_getCheckout()->createOrders();
```

I could not find where `createOrders()` function locate, so where i could find that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this file.

```
Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping.php
```

arround line no. 710 there is function

```
public function createOrders()
```